# JScrollPane don't appear on JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I have next problem, JScrollPane don't appear on JTextArea and I don't know why?
I tried in many ways but nothing, it don't want to show me! I put below a part of the code.
All appears correctly, JFame, JTextArea, text inside JTextArea, all without JScrollPane.
Please, can somebody help me?

```
package pachet;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import static javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import static javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED;



public class Design {
    private final JFrame x;
    
    private final JPanel panou_rezultate=new JPanel();
    
    private final JLabel aziL=new JLabel("Azi");
    private final JLabel saptamanaL=new JLabel("Ultimile 7 zile");
    private final JLabel lunaL=new JLabel("Ultimile 30 zile");
    private final JLabel totalL=new JLabel("De la inceput");
        
    private final JTextArea aziArea=new JTextArea(30,60);
    private final JTextArea saptamanaArea=new JTextArea(30,60);
    private final JTextArea lunaArea=new JTextArea(30,60);
    private final JTextArea totalArea=new JTextArea(30,60);
    
    private final JScrollPane totalScrol=new JScrollPane(totalArea,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
        JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS); //here it is created scroll

    public Design(JFrame x) {
        this.x = x;
        functie(); 
    }
    
    
    private void functie(){
       
        x.add(panou_rezultate,BorderLayout.CENTER);
       
        panou_rezultate.setLayout(metoda());
        
        panou_rezultate.add(totalScrol); //here is added scroll to panel
                
        PrelucrareDate y=new PrelucrareDate();
        aziArea.setText(y.getAziP());
        String abc="";
        for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
            abc=abc+"she is beautiful\n";
        }
        totalArea.setText(abc);   //totalArea text area is filled by many sentences, so scroll must appear   
        
       
    }
   
   
    public GroupLayout metoda(){
        
        GroupLayout gl= new GroupLayout(panou_rezultate);
        panou_rezultate.setLayout(gl);
        
        gl.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        gl.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);       
        
        GroupLayout.SequentialGroup sg=gl.createSequentialGroup();
        
            sg.addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)  //de schimbat
                    .addComponent(aziL)
                    .addComponent(aziArea)
                    );
            sg.addPreferredGap(RELATED, 
                        GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 
                        Short.MAX_VALUE);
            sg.addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)  //de schimbat
                    .addComponent(saptamanaL)
                    .addComponent(saptamanaArea)
                    );
            sg.addPreferredGap(RELATED, 
                        GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 
                        Short.MAX_VALUE);
            sg.addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)  //de schimbat
                    .addComponent(lunaL)
                    .addComponent(lunaArea)
                    );
            sg.addPreferredGap(RELATED, 
                        GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 
                        Short.MAX_VALUE);
            sg.addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)  //de schimbat
                    .addComponent(totalL)
                    .addComponent(totalArea)
                    );
            sg.addPreferredGap(RELATED, 
                        GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 
                        Short.MAX_VALUE);
             
        gl.setHorizontalGroup(sg);
        
        
        
        GroupLayout.ParallelGroup pg_etichete=gl.createParallelGroup(BASELINE);
        GroupLayout.ParallelGroup pg_arii_text=gl.createParallelGroup();
        
        
            pg_etichete.addComponent(aziL);
            pg_etichete.addComponent(saptamanaL);
            pg_etichete.addComponent(lunaL);
            pg_etichete.addComponent(totalL);
            
            pg_arii_text.addComponent(aziArea);
            pg_arii_text.addComponent(saptamanaArea);
            pg_arii_text.addComponent(lunaArea);
            pg_arii_text.addComponent(totalArea);
        

        GroupLayout.SequentialGroup sgv=gl.createSequentialGroup(); //secvential grup pe verticala
        
        sgv.addPreferredGap(RELATED, 
                        GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 
                        Short.MAX_VALUE);
        sgv.addGroup(pg_etichete);
        sgv.addGroup(pg_arii_text);
        sgv.addPreferredGap(RELATED,25,25);
        
        gl.setVerticalGroup(sgv);
        
    return gl;    
    }
    
}
```

I thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you need to go have a look at [How to Use Scroll Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) - the `JScrollPane` should wrap the component you want to be scrollable, this is typically done via the constructor but you can also use `JScrollPane#setViewportView` ... DO NOT use `add` :/

Comment: Can you be more explicitly? Give me more details like some code lines and what to replace?

Comment: ... `totalScrol=new JScrollPane(totalArea)` ...

Comment: It exists on 12 line of my code, look at it:         private final JScrollPane totalScrol=new JScrollPane(totalArea,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
        JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS); //here it is created scroll,  i cannot see any problema!

Comment: Ok, missed that, my guess is it's the `GroupLayout`.  So I modified your code to use a `GridBagLayout` and have no issue.  Although, I'm left wondering if a `JTable` would be a better choice over all

Answer (score 0):

```
    panou_rezultate.setLayout(metoda());
    panou_rezultate.add(totalScrol); //here is added scroll to panel
```

Look at all the code generated by your IDE when you use a `GroupLayout`.

There is all kinds of complex code to specify the constraints used by the `GroupLayout` and then the `addComponent(...)` method is used. Because of this complexity the `GroupLayout` is typically only used by IDE generated code.

You can't simply use the add(...) method to add components to a group layout.

Our recommendation would be to NOT use the IDE to generate your layout code. Then you are in full control.

Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for working examples to get you started.